# Are users who already posted an answer notified about offering a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty, notifications

What happens in the following situation: I posted some question, soon after one person response in the answer. However the answer was not enough detailed for me: I posted the comment encouraging this person to provide some more details, however he didn't do that. Then I started the bounty for this question. Now I would like to ask, whether this person will receive a message about activity in this topic or should I (at least) post some comment to be sure that this user will at least see my bounty?

Comment: Maybe not of immediate relevance to the question, but if you want more details on a specific part, follow-up questions are also a legitimate angle of attack.

Comment: A related feature request on main meta: [Can there be a notification for bounties started on questions you've asked or answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68881)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Placing a bounty on a question will not directly notify a user that answered it.

I am not convinced it is useful to inform the answerer again that you want a more detailed answer, but it would not be redundant with the bounty and not out-of-line either.

Comment: Thank you, and how about editting the question? It will cause that this user would get the message about activity in this question?

Comment: No. (If they favorited it, they may notice that way, but this would be indepedent of the fact they answered.) Generally, post owners are often notified of activities on their posts, but the question post is not the post of the answerer.